# Is multiplication operator bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with exponentially decaying weight

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the Hilbert space $H=L^2[\mathbb{R},e^{-x^2}dx]$. Is the operator
$M:D\subset H\rightarrow H$ defined as

$Mf(x)=xf(x)$ bounded ?

Comment: You could maybe try integration by parts on $<xf,xf>^2$, differentiating any $x, x^2$ which pop up and try to express the result in terms of $<f,f>^2$.

Comment: What is $D$?$\,\,$

Comment: @zhw $D$ is the domain of the operator, since it could be the case that it is not defined for all of $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}, n = 1,2, \dots $

Comment: This is the standard technique to prove un-boundedness.  However, it seems like in this case of exponential weight, I get terms like $n^2 e^{-n^2}$ which is bounded.

Comment: But on the other side you have $e^{-n^2}.$

Comment: Aah of course. That was dumb of me. Thanks.